# Unable to get navigation bar to appear in xcode, double click doesn't register

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uinavigationbar

I was working through the swift tutorial:

https://www.raywenderlich.com/115279/swift-2-tutorial-part-2-a-simple-ios-app

On the section (about 1/3 way down)

[image]

But I'm noticing a problem when I attempt these steps in my xcode environment. I am able to successfully embed a navigation bar, but "double clicking" doesn't allow me to set the text at all, in fact it really doesn't let me do anything just highlighting the nav bar region:

See:

[image]

I can also put up code at request, but being this is so early in the project, I haven't coded really anything yet, it seems more like a UX challenge. Am I missing some particular setting in Xcode editor that allows the text to be highlighted, or has the guide skipped some trivial, but necessary step to making this work?

@sschale's answer is a good solution:

For user's that come across the post, it isn't obvious where that menu is. After some digging I found that you need to hit a certain middle icon (in the red box) so it is blue to find the form. Image attached:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sometimes it can be hard for it to register there. You can edit it in the right sidebar directly, when the Navigation Item is selected:

[image]